# How to get custom message from i18n to model

Tags: java, playframework

I would like to set message for Constraint like this

```
import play.i18n.Messages;

public class User extends Model {

    @Constraints.Required(message = @Messages.get("validation.required"))
    private String login;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a customized validation message, you must create a file named `messages` on `conf` directory that contain your customized message first. Please check the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaI18N)

Then, suppose you have a model like following:

```
public class MyModel extends Model {

    @Constraints.MaxLength(value = 4, message = "validation.limit")
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "column_name")
    public String columnName;
}
```

The `messages` files contain like following:

```
validation.limit=Please limit the input
validation.required=This field is required to fill
```

Notice that I mark the `@Constraint.MaxLength` with `message` value `"validation.limit"` and on `messages` file I specify the value of that with `Please limit the input` message.

You can find :

- If you input the `columnName` value with string whose length greater than `4`, you will get validation message `Please limit the input`. (corresponding to key `validation.limit` on `messages` file)
- If you submit empty value on `columnName`, you will get validation message `This field is required to fill`. Note that `validation.required` is the default message key for `@Required` annotation.

Hope it is useful for you.. ;)